# SUS Questions- Infrequent Experience

Tags: usability, usability-testing, sus

We started using the SUS to baseline our online activation process experience, but the first question:

> 1. I think that I would like to use this system frequently.

doesn't suite an infrequent experience such as mobile SIM card activation which doesn't happen frequently.

Appreciate your advice on this.

Answer (score 2):

With SUS, you have some room to play around with the words without effecting the results too much.

For example, you could change it to:

*I think that I would like to use this service frequently.*

or

*I think that I would like to use this product frequently.*

Whatever works in your context.

[This is backed up by this article.](https://measuringu.com/change-standardized/)

> Small changes are less likely to have a big impact. For example when using the SUS, it’s been shown that changing the word “system” to the name of the product (e.g. QuickBooks) or the type of system (e.g. website) adds clarity for respondents without sacrificing its psychometric properties.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any feedback on that question? In my experience people take questions like this usually abstractly and answer them without thinking that they won't use it frequently. 
You are not asking about the task, you are asking about how they went through with the task and the walk-through might be pleasant enough to answer that as "Strongly agree". I understand the question is not perfect in your case, but I would give it time and collect feedback and see.